# Embedding Images and matplotlib Plots together on on tk canvas

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

A few years ago I wrote a script in python2 that would pull images and generate plots and show them together in one gui, [following this old documentation](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_canvas_sgskip.html). However, I'm trying to update this to python3, and I've run into an issue with the way that plots are put on tk windows in the latest version of matplotlib. [There are updated guides](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html) for how to embed matplotlib graphs in tk windows, of course, but these don't seem to be exactly what I want, since I want to plot various images and graphs together.

Currently:

```
# Start by creating the GUI as root
root=Tk()
root.wm_title("JADESView")

# Create the canvas 
canvas=Canvas(root, height=canvasheight, width=canvaswidth)

# Plot the EAZY SED
#image = Image.open(EAZY_files+str(current_id)+"_EAZY_SED.png")
image = getEAZYimage(current_id)

# Crop out the thumbnails
image = cropEAZY(image)

photo = resizeimage(image)
item4 = canvas.create_image(eazy_positionx, eazy_positiony, image=photo)
Label(root, text="EAZY FIT", font=('helvetica', int(textsizevalue*1.5))).place(x=eazytext_positionx, y = eazytext_positiony)

# Plot the BEAGLE SED
#new_image = Image.open(BEAGLE_files+str(current_id)+"_BEAGLE_SED.png")
new_image = getBEAGLEimage(current_id)
new_photo = resizeimage(new_image)
item5 = canvas.create_image(beagle_positionx, beagle_positiony, image=new_photo)
Label(root, text="BEAGLE FIT", font=('helvetica', int(textsizevalue*1.5))).place(x=beagletext_positionx, y = beagletext_positiony)
    
canvas.pack(side = TOP, expand=True, fill=BOTH)

# Plot the thumbnails
fig_photo_objects = np.empty(0, dtype = 'object')
fig_photo_objects = create_thumbnails(canvas, fig_photo_objects, current_id, current_index, defaultstretch)
```

I create a tk.canvas object, and then use canvas.create_image to place two PIL photo objects, with labels (the "EAZY SED" and BEAGLE SED"), and this still works with python3. However, the create_thumbnails function I've written creates individual figure objects and then calls a function "draw_figure" to embed them, which I'll post below, but it's from the tk example I linked above:

```
def draw_figure(canvas, figure, loc=(0, 0)):
    """ Draw a matplotlib figure onto a Tk canvas

    loc: location of top-left corner of figure on canvas in pixels.
    Inspired by matplotlib source: lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py
    """
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasAgg(figure)
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    figure_x, figure_y, figure_w, figure_h = figure.bbox.bounds
    figure_w, figure_h = int(figure_w), int(figure_h)
    photo = PhotoImage(master=canvas, width=figure_w, height=figure_h)

    # Position: convert from top-left anchor to center anchor
    canvas.create_image(loc[0] + figure_w/2, loc[1] + figure_h/2, image=photo)

    # Unfortunately, there's no accessor for the pointer to the native renderer
    tkagg.blit(photo, figure_canvas_agg.get_renderer()._renderer, colormode=2)

    # Return a handle which contains a reference to the photo object
    # which must be kept live or else the picture disappears
    return photo
```

And this breaks in all sorts of ways.

I'm open to overhauling how everything is done, but I don't see examples that show how this sort of thing might work. The examples for the latest version of matplotlib all explain that you should use `FigureCanvasTkAgg`, but I don't exactly know how to use this if I already have an existing canvas with photos embedded.

Any help would be appreciated, and I can also explain more if necessary!

Comment: So, on further experimentation, if, inside of the create_thumbnails function, if I don't use draw_figure, but instead just run FigureCanvasTkAgg and get_tk_widget().pack(), the individual matplotlib graphs (the thumbnails) will show up, but as far as I can tell, this is vastly different from how it used to be, in that I can't specify where the plots are placed exactly on the canvas. They just appear in a big column, and the size of the canvas is *also* changed. Non-ideal.